# Make payment at PayPal before SubmitOrder

Tags: paypal, checkout

This question is based on a project done through the  MvcMusicStore tutorial.

Same technologies are also implemented in my site e.g. (MVC3, Sql Server 2008 SSMS & EF Code First)

I have implemented PayPal Web Standards payment at my project. Thanks to @Arun, i have referred to his site here http://www.arunrana.net/2012/01/paypal-integration-in-mvc3-and-razor.html

**Situation at MvcMusicStore:**

My project is similar to the data flow of MvcMusicStore. As you can see in this link, http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-music-store/mvc-music-store-part-9

In this tutorial, Jon Galloway has inserted a Payment field in the AddressAndPayment.cshtml page (but for simplicity purposes he made all products to be purchased for free by typing the keyword 'Free' - which would allow the user to checkout by clicking SubmitOrder and saving the Order in database)

**Situation at My Project:**

My question is about the workflow that i intend to apply.

When user adds items to shopping cart and reviews items in the Cart.

**I want to:**

1. Redirect user to PayPal to make payment upon clicking Checkout
2. After User make payment, return the user to AddressAndPayment.cshtml page
3. User then enters information and submit order

**Is this work flow even right to begin with?**

**If yes, how do i convert these variables from my project;**

```
 Product.Title
 Product.Quantity
 Product.UnitPrice
```

**to match these PayPal variables?**

```
 Item_Name
 Amount
 Quantity
```

Comment: Thanks for editing @Tichodroma! Do you have any advice as to how i should proceed?

Answer (score 0):

Well i figured it out myself.

My first question, **"Is this work flow even right to begin with?"**

I have implemented it successfully. I cant say it is 100% right way of implementing it. It depends on your own system workflow. As for MvcMusicStudio, i cannot think of any other methods than this.

As for the second question, all i did was call a **foreach loop** and looped the PayPal variables. You will see it in more detail on Arun's website (link provided in the question thread above).

Thank you.